# Chrome Extension: If my app does not have a default_popup set then I am not able to view Inspect Popup. How to debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If my Google Chrome extension does not have a default_popup as I need to use `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`which is not called if the property 'default_popup' is set in `mainfest.json` file.

**Problem**

As shown in screen shot given below the `inspect popup` is disabled which is the key to open the dev. console for the extension.

[image]
**How to debug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Extensions page of Chrome (`chrome://extensions/`), and enable developer mode if you haven't done so already. Click the link next to "Inspect views" to inspect your extension's background page.

[image]

Note that your extension's background page is *not* the same thing as its popup. Inspecting the popup and the background page of an extension that has both will give you two completely different inspectors!

Comment: thanks for the answer. however could you please elaborate `two completely different inspectors!`

Answer (score 1):

Each html page your extension loads needs a separate devtools instance.

You can find all inspectable views at "chrome://inspect"

If you want to break on uncaught exceptions and the devtools are not opened yet, you can use a function [wait_for_devtools](https://gist.github.com/kzahel/6eb6ebaa7a495e7329bc0392305a2db3) to delay your startup function (e.g. after window.onload or document ready)